# How to select entry every 5 minutes with SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I need to return data from a SQLite table with timestamps, and select one timestamp every 5 minutes. The table contains SQLite timestamp strings, one per minute, that are rounded to the minute.

In other words I need to have a WHERE condition like: "minutes % 5 = 0". But I can't seem to do it and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm also filtering the timestamps to be from the last 24 hours: `dt > datetime('now','-1 day')`. That one works.

So far I've tried:

```
SELECT dt, y FROM mytable WHERE dt > datetime('now','-1 day') AND strftime(dt, '%M') % 5 = 0 ORDER BY dt
```

and:

```
SELECT dt, y FROM mytable WHERE dt > datetime('now','-1 day') AND cast(strftime(dt, '%M') as int) % 5 = 0 ORDER BY dt
```

and:

```
SELECT dt, y FROM mytable WHERE dt > datetime('now','-1 day') AND mod(minute(dt),5) = 0 ORDER BY dt
```

... and various combinations of these.

I think SQLite doesn't support minute(), so that's why the last one doesn't work.

Comment: strftime takes format as it's first argument and timestring as the second.

Comment: Thank you! Here's the working SQLite query: `SELECT dt, y FROM mytable WHERE dt > datetime('now','-1 day') AND strftime('%M', dt) % 5 = 0 ORDER BY dt`

Answer (score 1):

As mention by algrid, the [strftime() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) takes its parameters in a different order:

```
> select strftime('12:34:56', '%M');

> select strftime('%M', '12:34:56');
34
```